# How does the Magento Newsletter module handle queueing

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, newsletter

I'm working on a project and the client surprisingly has 90,000 email subscribers from their old site.  They want to send out a newsletter when we launch.  I'm recommending MailChimp but I'm also curious how well the Magento Newsletter works, could it handle a newsletter shot of that size?

How does Magento queue it's sending newsletters?  Does it send them in batches of 50 every 5min or something similar?  What kind of impact would this have on server performance.  Can you adjust it's frequency?

I imagine this is all done by cron.

Comment: Theoretically, Magento can handle newsletter shoot-out of any size, but you should also consider the burden, it will place upon your Mail Server. There are some drawbacks of using same mail server for both transaction and promotional mails.

Comment: @Prateek, interesting what kind of drawbacks would their be with promotional emails that would not effect transnational emails.  I can only think of the mailserver IP not being whitelisted but this would effect both types of emails.

Comment: The drawbacks wouldn't be specific to any particular type of mail. At this situation, my concern would be getting blocked by ISPs, if I shoot out a mail burst from my own mail server. In that case, I wouldn't be able to send even transaction mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after checking *app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/config.xml* I see that there is a cron set up to schedule the sending on the newsletters, that calls *newsletter/observer::scheduledSend*:

```
public function scheduledSend($schedule)
{
    $countOfQueue  = 3;
    $countOfSubscritions = 20;

    $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/queue')->getCollection()
        ->setPageSize($countOfQueue)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->addOnlyForSendingFilter()
        ->load();

     $collection->walk('sendPerSubscriber', array($countOfSubscritions));
}
```

I think this means it sends 3 batches of 20 subscriptions every CRON cycle which on our server is every 5 mins.  Not 100% sure on this but will keep looking.

Comment: In newsletter queue, some mails sent twice time to some users. How to prevent multiple time mail sending?